How to Import SSL Certificate PFX on Weblogic 12
I only have windows IIS export pfx file ,Weblogic need identity.jks &Trust.jks
I find this command for identity.jks
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore certs_bundle.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore identity.jks -deststoretype JKS -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass <src_store_password> -deststorepass <dest_store_password> -destkeypass <dest_Key_password>

so How to export Trust.jks from pfx
Please help me,thank you all

This documentation could help.
